# Generate JavaScript code in a Java application

Tags: javascript, java, code-generation

I've seen similar questions but not the same.
I have a java application which sends a get and post requests. Now the issue is that the requests need to have a CSRTF TOKEN which I can't get from the ReasteastClient.getcookies method, so I've written a JavaScript code to get this token. I'm trying to generate a JavaScript code from my java application and to get the function response.

Any way to do so ??
Thank you all.

Comment: Which kind of application is it? Kind of REST service?

Comment: Are we talking about a service or jsp/jsf/...?

Comment: yes, a REST service

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

To generate JavaScript code in Java you need to follow following steps

1.create your JavaScript File and add your function which retrieves CSRTF TOKEN

By adding function :

```
$.get('CSRFTokenManager.do', function(data) {
   var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
   token =data;
   document.cookie='X-CSRF-Token='+token;
   XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
       this.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',token);
       //dojo.cookie("X-CSRF-Token", "");

       return send.apply(this, arguments);
   };
});
```

2.Save this as Jsfunctions.js and use it in your java code like below.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
// read script file
engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:/Scripts/Jsfunctions.js"), 
StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
// call function from script file
inv.invokeFunction("yourFunction", "param");
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: Thank you very much !
What should bt here : inv.invokeFunction("yourFunction", "param");  ?